# How to reshape a 1D Tensorflow Tensor to a 4D Tensor of rank 4

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a 1D Tensorflow Tensor that represents an image. I originally had (2, 2, 3) shaped RGB image, but by the time the data gets to my model it has been normalized, converted to grayscale, and flattened.

I am trying to reconstruct the image so that I can run some convolutions on it. I tried reshaping it, squeezing it, and expanding it a few different ways, but I cannot get it to shape up as a 4D array for conv2d.

Below is the code I am using.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# This was originally a 2x2 RGB image which was converted to grayscale and flattened
tf_1d_input = tf.Variable([0.1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]) 
tf_4d_reshape = tf.reshape(tf_1d_input, [1, 2, 2, 1])
tf_conv_layer = tf.nn.conv2d(tf_4d_reshape, (3,3), [1, 1, 1, 1], 'SAME')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(tf.rank(tf_4d_reshape))
    sess.run(tf_conv_layer)
# ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 1 for 'Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [1,2,2,1], [2].
```

Is there a step that I am missing, or do I simply not understand what reshape does/what conv2d expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tensorflow, the filter argument of `conv2d` must be a tensor corresponding to the weights of the convolution, not a convolution size.

```
tf_1d_input = tf.Variable([0.1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]) 
tf_4d_reshape = tf.reshape(tf_1d_input, [1, 2, 2, 1])
w = tf.zeros([3, 3, 1, 10])
tf_conv_layer = tf.nn.conv2d(tf_4d_reshape, w, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'SAME') # no error anymore
```

Of course the example above works but is not useful. You will find more concrete examples of how to initialize weights with initializers in tf tutorials, for example this one on [MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/pros/).

Comment: Thanks.  I realized this a few hours after posting last night. That's what I get for switching back and forth between Keras, Tensorflow, etc.  The error confused me, because when I tried `print(tf.rank(tf_4d_reshape)) it was saying that it was rank 1, which matched the error message. I'm still not sure why that was the case, but adding properly formatted weight tensors does address my problem.